# AWS cloudsearch console providing different search result

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudsearch

In Aws console when I search **"authority"** it provide me the result which have the term **"author"** which is not at all feasible according to my search term. Is there any configuration problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of *stemming*, which is a trick search engines use to try to return matches for the same root word. For example, a query for "cooking" should probably also match "cook", "cooked", etc. This is accomplished by indexing the word stems, and you can control the extent to which CloudSearch stems.

The default for English is *full algorithmic stemming* and what you have here is a case of that algorithm not returning the desired results. Your options are to turn down stemming to *light* or *none*, or to index this as a literal field rather than text (probably not what you want but I don't know much about your use case).

Here are the docs for [Configuring Text Analysis Schemes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/configuring-analysis-schemes.html) and [Text Processing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/text-processing.html) in CloudSearch.